# How to integrate Simulaqron on ProjectQ

Tags: programming, teleportation, projectq

I am trying to simulate quantum teleportation on ProjectQ using simulaqron (enabling me to use quantum internet for teleportation) however I am not sure if my approach is right. In the working paper of simulaqron its written that programming via another backend like ProjectQ is very much possible. However when I am testing quantum teleporation I am not getting any output

[Alice's code] followed by [Bob's code]

```
  from projectq.ops import All, CNOT, H, Measure, Rz, X, Z
    from projectq import MainEngine
    from projectq.meta import Dagger, Control
    from cqc.pythonLib import CQCConnection, qubit
    import simulaqron

def main():

    with CQCConnection("Alice") as Alice:
        eng = MainEngine()
        c1, c2 = create_bell_pair(eng)
        tel1 = eng.allocate_qubit()
        Alice.sendQubit((c1, "Bob"))
        H | tel1
        CNOT | (tel1, c2)
        H | tel1
        Measure | tel1
        Measure | c2
        to_print = "App {}: Measurement outcomes are: a={}, b={}".format(Alice.name, int(tel1), int(c2))
        print("|" + "-" * (len(to_print) + 2) + "|")
        print("| " + to_print + " |")
        print("|" + "-" * (len(to_print) + 2) + "|")

        # Send corrections to Bob
        Alice.sendClassical("Bob", int(tel1), int(c2))


def create_bell_pair(eng):
    b1 = eng.allocate_qubit()
    b2 = eng.allocate_qubit()

    H | b1
    CNOT | (b1, b2)

    return b1, b2

main()    

// new file for bob
from projectq.ops import All, CNOT, H, Measure, Rz, X, Z
from projectq import MainEngine
from projectq.meta import Dagger, Control
from cqc.pythonLib import CQCConnection, qubit
import simulaqron

#####################################################################################################
#
# main
#
def main():

        # Initialize the connection
        with CQCConnection("Bob") as Bob:

            # Make an EPR pair with Alice
            qB=Bob.recvQubit(c1, "Alice")

            # Receive info about corrections
            data=Bob.recvClassical()
            message=list(data)
            a=message[0]
            b=message[1]

            # Apply corrections
            if b==1:
                    X | qB
            if a==1:
                    Z | qB

            # Measure qubit
            Measure | qB
            to_print="App {}: Measurement outcome is:  {}".format(Bob.name,int(qB))
            print("|"+"-"*(len(to_print)+2)+"|")
            print("| "+to_print+" |")
            print("|"+"-"*(len(to_print)+2)+"|")

##################################################################################################
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you have executed the command "simulaqron set backend projectq" in your shell, in order to set the projectq backend.

Moreover, in your Bob's code there is a reference to c1 which is undefined, in:

qB=Bob.recvQubit(c1, "Alice")

Comment: Hi @Oldville !  Thank you so much for the help. I have already done that ( simulaqron set backend projectq ), yet I am not getting any output. Is the wrong syntax of recvQubit causing this? if so what is the right syntax?